# How to create a plot with CI in netlogo?

Tags: plot, netlogo

I am planning to see how attitudes are formed throughout the simulations (500 ticks).

500 agents' attitudes is indexed by their x-axis.

SD, kurtosis, ER-index, and distribution histogram will be DVs.

I am planning to insert plots in the paper besides the averaged final numbers.

1)
If I run 100 simulations for 500 ticks, each tick (1 ~ 500) has 100 SD, kurtosis, and ER-index values. I'd like to plot the mean and CIs.

If my question is unclear, please see Song, H., & Boomgaarden, H. G. (2017). Dynamic spirals put to test: An agent-based model of reinforcing spirals between selective exposure, interpersonal networks, and attitude polarization. Journal of Communication, 67(2), 256-281.
https://academic.oup.com/joc/article-abstract/67/2/256/4082400

2)
After 500 ticks, the final distribution is produced. Each pxcor has 100 values of the numbers of agents in that pxcor. Like the question 1, I'd like to draw a plot with CI and mean. But in this case, the x-axis is not the time, but the pxcor.

Is there any way to do it in netlogo?

[kurtosis sample plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEdOw.png)

[attitudes sample histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTJUC.png)

Comment: Is there some particular aspect of this you're stuck on? I can't think of any reason this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: The biggest problem is I don't know how to start. I cannot find any relevant codes in here or the internet. So far I learned how to export the results (the dvs after 500 ticks) to .txt file and get averages and standard deviations and have no idea about the plots. Literally any piece of advice would be helpful to me!

Comment: The way to solve a problem that's too big for you is to solve a smaller, simpler problem first, then keep adding to the solution. For example, let me pick out the phrase "the x-axis is not the time, but the pxcor" from your question. I can answer that: it means you need to use `plotxy` instead of `plot`. You could start by practicing using `plotxy`. How about trying to make a plot where you call `plotxy` once where the x coordinate is each pxcor, and the y coordinate is literally anything all, like a random number? If you can do that, you'll have made progress towards solving the full problem.